# Small space at start of nav bar preventing centering

Tags: html, css, web

So I'm using an unordered list to create a horizontal navigation bar and I want to center that toolbar.  However, there's a small space at the start of the toolbar that is causing it to be slightly off center when I use text-align:center.  Here's a pic of it not centered:

[image: Uncentered nav bar]

I would like to get "Home" right up against the left most border.  But there seems to be about 20px space.  Here is a pic of the nav bar centered:

[image: Centered nav bar]

I feel like its off center because the 'Home' button is slightly off center with "Tristan Gianola."  Here is the CSS & HTML:

```css
nav{font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 margin-top:50px;
 border:solid 5px red;
 text-align:center;}
nav ul{border:solid 5px green;}
nav ul li{display:inline;
  margin:2px;}
nav ul li strong{text-decoration:none;
    color:#003434;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    padding:10px;}
nav ul li a{text-decoration:none;
   color:#f2f2f2;
   background:#003434;
   padding:10px;
   border-bottom:solid 1px white;}
nav ul li a:hover{background:grey;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
 <!--site navigation / toolbar-->
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
   <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
   <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 
 <h1>Tristan Gianola</h1>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for reading/answering in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ul>`'s by [default have 40px padding on the left](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-display), remove that and it will be perfectly centered:

```
nav ul{
   border:solid 5px green;
   padding:0;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqw0aafr/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a padding-left in your `ul`

```
nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    border:solid 5px green;
}
```

This should fix it. :)